# Getting all unique values stored in a many-to-many field

Tags: django

I have a many-to-many field called `categories` and I would like to get distinct values stored in that field.

The following is my model:

```
class Book (models.Model):
    categories=models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name = 'categories', blank = True, null=True)
```

Here is my Category model:

```
class Category (MPTTModel):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
```

I'd like to get every single one of the categories related to a book. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get categories related to *one* instance of book, do `book_inst.category_set.all()`. There will not be duplicates.

But I think, you want to get all `Categories` which are related to *any* `Book`, you can do:

```
Category.objects.filter(categories__in=[Book.objects.all()]).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want, but it's saying `Cannot resolve keyword 'book' into field` because I don't have the `book` field in my `Category` table. Instead I have the `categories` field in my `Book` table.

Comment: @user1328021, use `categoies__in` instead of `book__in` as that is what you are using as reverse related name. I didn't paid attention to it.

Comment: Your related name is backwards. You should use the name the relation would use to obtain *its* related objects, so for the Category relation, you would use related_name='book' (or 'books') in the Book model -- a Category looks up its Book instances via 'books'.

Comment: I believe it should be `categories__in=Book.objects.all()`, without additional square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a reverse lookup from the category side to check if there is book for that category if yes, add to the resultant query set. Since, the related_name argument in the Book is 'categories', your reverse lookup would look something like this.

```
  Category.objects.filter(categories__in = Book.objects.all())
```

Comment: I want to get all categories that exist for every book. Wouldn't this limit it to only one book?

Comment: THanks but not I'm getting `'ManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`. Could it be because I'm using MPTT model type?

Comment: Sorry I made an ignorant mistake. I have re-edited my answer. Check it out!

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal, this will give duplicate entries, you need to use `.distinct()`. However, you shouldn't be copy-paste from some else's answer.

Comment: @Rohan - when I look at the time stamps in the history Raunak seems to have arrived at this answer before you.

Comment: @KEV, If you look at the edits earlier answer were not correct and then ultimately arrived to correct one same as mine. Let it be though.

Comment: @Rohan: sorry man it was a ignorant mistake I never realized that I was in a way giving ur answer. Secondly I was not aware if I could edit other's answer otherwise, would have done that.

Comment: @user1328021: Dude could please changed answered to Rohan's thread please. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rohan - well if we're all happy then I'm sure both answers can happily co-exist in harmony :)

Comment: @kev, I agree. I just wanted to make a point. No more issue from my side!

Comment: Wait, not sure what I should do? Do I need to change who I gave the answer to? Let me know.

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal OK I changed to Rohan's thread. BTW I'm not a dude!