# traverse m2m with filter in django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-views

I'm trying to return filtered values from a m2m relationship to use in a template. Should be trivial, but I can't get it to work.

I tried to do it in the model as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223990/how-do-i-perform-query-filtering-in-django-templates) and didn't get it to work. Now I'm trying a potentially easier way in the view, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986010/getting-all-unique-values-stored-in-a-many-to-many-field), but can't get it to work either.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activity_nm = models.CharField(max_length=60)  
    enddt = models.DateField()
    groups =  models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.activity_nm     

class Group (models.Model):
    group_nm = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.group_nm        



def group_details_page(request, group_nm):
    g=Activity.objects.filter(groups__in=[Group.objects.filter(group_nm=group_nm)],enddt__gt=now)
    return render_to_response('group_details_page.html', {'group': g},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My goal is to return all activities for one group where the activity's end date > now to be available in the template.

Thanks.

EDIT: There error received is:
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'

EDIT2: It looks like there is more to this problem than I thought. I can't get any values to return now.

```
g=Group.objects.all()
```

does not return values to the template. The template resolves the base.html call, but trying to get just `{{ group.group_nm }}` to appear does not work.

EDIT3: Got it to return group names (sorry for the confusion).

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: The error would help, wouldn't it. Added now.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `RequestContext`? If you don't do special [context preprocessing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) you don't need it.

Comment: You need the `Group.group_nm` in your template?

Comment: Yes, it's displayed in the header.

Comment: I'm using RequestContext for [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs), example [here](http://obroll.com/example-how-to-use-django-pagination-in-django-1-3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it and the solution is really simple.

With `g=Activity.objects.filter(groups__in=[Group.objects.filter(group_nm=group_nm)],enddt__gt=now)` you put an iterable in a list (`[QuerySet]`) which django doesn't know how to index.

The solution is to dump the list comprehension:

```
g=Activity.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.filter(group_nm=group_nm),enddt__gt=now)
```

and then it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks @RickyA, but I get the same int() ... not QuerySet error.

Comment: Thanks @RickyA, it looks like I'm having more trouble than I realized (see edit above).

Comment: I get the same result as @mVChr solution. Will return base.html, but no values.

Comment: Dont forget that you are also filtering on enddt. That was my problem when I tested your code.

Comment: Even removing that filter gives the same result: `g=Activity.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.filter(group_nm=group_nm))#,enddt__gt=now)`

I also removed the pagination that used the contextprocessor to simplify things

Comment: And if you debug through the view (or `print(g)` ) does it contain data or is it empty? Just to make sure fetching is the problem...

Comment: That was it. The statement **did** return data, so I took a fresh look at the template, which was not displaying correctly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is filter the `activity_set` (see [backward relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)) from the group specified by `group_nm`:

```
def group_details_page(request, group_nm):
    group_instance = Group.objects.get(group_nm=group_nm)
    activities = group_instance.activity_set.objects.filter(enddt__gt=now)
    return render_to_response(...etc...)
```

Comment: I made the change but get this error: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'objects'. It is a M2M relationship and not FK.

Comment: @jabs Try filtering directly from the manager then: `group_instance.activity_set.filter(enddt__gt=now)`

Comment: The query won't return anything. It resolves since it brings up base.html, but no values. I modified it slightly `g=group_instance.activity_set.all()` to eliminate data or date issues but it still returns no values.